# Determine if Push Notifications alert view is displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c

The first time that a user accesses my app, they are asked whether they want to allow push notifications. At the same time, I have some animations going on. The push notification question is obscuring these animations.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to determine whether this alert view is being displayed. If I can determine when it gets dismissed (regardless of what the user chooses), I could delay the start of the animations until this event occurs. Despite much research, I am at a loss as to whether this can be done or not.

Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT** 
Thanks for the suggestions. One thing that I didn't explain is that the animations initiate from the initial view controller (SplashScreenViewController) while the push notifications happen in the AppDelegate. I need a good way to get these two classes to communicate without creating a race condition.

Comment: You could take a different approach. Don't try to register for notifications until the animations are complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're focused on the specific problem, which is that the alert is obscuring your animations.  However, the problem you should be trying to solve is: Am I asking for remote notification registration, and if so, has it been given or not?

You should be able to do this with a combination of the methods available on `UIApplication` and `UIApplicationDelegate`.  Perhaps something like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]) {
        // Show animation
    }
    else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:<#notification type#>];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Show animation
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Show animation
}
@end
```

Comment: I agree with you, but what you propose is tricky, so I was looking for something simpler. The push notification is in the AppDelegate and my animations are in the initial view controller. I took your suggestion, and resolved this via a tricky interaction between the two classes using notifications, `NSUserDefaults`, and `NSTimers`. Looks like it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why you'd need to utilize `NSUserDefaults` and `NSTimers`, it seems like just posting an `NSNotification` via `NSNotificationCenter` would get the job done.  But I'm glad it worked out.